# files/.../children returns bad page tokens

Tags: google-drive-api

Calling .../files/root/children seems to return bad nextPageToken values as of a few days ago. I'm seeing this on two accounts, both reproducible with api-explorer:
- Note that selfLink and nextLink are identical in the response
- The same nextPageToken is returned for every request, on two different accounts, for different folders. 
- The children are always the same, if I pass the pageToken or not into the query
- The maxResults parameter is ignored, too.

So it appears that pageToken has no effect at all. Because I'm seeing the same nextPageToken returned for all kinds of different queries, I'm speculating that nextPageToken is bad.

I replaced part of the token with ..., and stripped of the https prefix from the URLs.

Request:

```
GET www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/root/children?maxResults=10&pageToken=!!%7C~EAI...CAG&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
 "kind": "drive#childList",
 "etag": ...,
 "selfLink": "www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/root/children?maxResults=10&pageToken=!!%7C~EAI...CAG",
 "nextPageToken": "!!|~EAI...CAG",
 "nextLink": "www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/root/children?maxResults=10&pageToken=!!%7C~EAI...CAG",
```

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that this is a bug affects pagination on children responses. We don't honor maxResults param and instead listing the whole directory. It should be fixed during this week.

Comment: Yes, both pagination and maxResults are now working again for me.